# How to make a 3d visualisation of different peat layer to show the height of each layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, visualisation, 3d-analyst, 3d-map, 3d-model

I have bore hole point data that has about 5 to 7 types of peat layer and also has several depths. I also have digital elevation data of the area.

I need to interpolate these layers separately, then visualise the layers sequentially in 3d.

Is it possible to to it with ArcGIS?

I want to add a Screen shot that may make my querry more clear:
[image]

My points include the measurement depth of 4 different quality pit layer. The left image is my data set and right image is what I want from my data. I want to visualize a block diagram of formation of each peat layer. I did not find a clear description or tutorial to make the block diagram in arcscene.:-(

Answer (score 2):

I did this many years ago in England/Ireland using the TIN module of ARC/INFO, so I would be surprised if the 3D Analyst module of ArcGIS for Desktop could not do the same and better.

My recollection is that I just created a TIN surface using the depth values for each of the peat types.

Nowadays I would look into using a terrain dataset, and there are various [Display options for a terrain dataset in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005v0000002r000000).